# How to select html inner most child value using xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have a html structure like below:

```
<tr>
<td> AAA </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a> BBB </a></td>
</tr>

//more rows like same as above...
```

How to select the values inside <td> tags? I want a list something like ['AAA', 'BBB', ...]

I tired with below query. But it fails to extract the vale of  second table row as  tag is present.

```
//table//td[1]/text()
```

Can anyone suggest more generic xpath query to capture values of all the <td> entries?

Thanks

Comment: Are you committed to XPath, or would a CSS selector work?

Comment: It is necessary to use Xpath?

Comment: Not necessary to use Xpath . I just want to scrap some table values from some html links. If it is possible to do using any other way that would be a big help. just need stick to python or any easy way to implement the code.

Comment: @hasi90 I replied below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using BeautifulSoup for parse your html , for install BeautifulSoup just make this : pip install beautifulsoup4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = """
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Programming Language</th>
      <th>Creator</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a> BBB </a></td>
      <td>Dennis Ritchie</td>
      <td>1972</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Python</td>
      <td>Guido Van Rossum</td>
      <td>1989</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ruby</td>
      <td>Yukihiro Matsumoto</td>
      <td>1995</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
"""
my_list = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "html.parser")
samples = soup.find_all("td")

for row in samples:
    print(row.get_text())
    my_list.append(row.get_text())

print(my_list)
```

Comment: Does this extract the value of  <td><a>Dennis Ritchie</a></td> ? Please note that there are two different table data tags. one is <td>Yukihiro Matsumoto</td> and the other is  <td><a>Yukihiro Matsumoto</a></td>. Thanks

Comment: @hasi90 , Yes, it also works including those tags ... I just validated it..even in the code I added the tag  <a> BBB </a>

Comment: Thanks. I just found out in xpath there have to add additional "\". before text() like this : //table//td[1]//text().